# Can't project data to robinson map with ggplot "no system list"

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgdal

I am trying to plot some points on a map in R following instructions found here
http://rpsychologist.com/working-with-shapefiles-projections-and-world-maps-in-ggplot

When I get to the line where I use the `rgdal:project` function though I get an error message

```
places_robin_df <- project(cbind(places_df$LONGITUDE, places_df$LATITUDE), proj="+init=ESRI:54030")
```

> Error in project(cbind(places_df$LONGITUDE, places_df$LATITUDE), proj = "+init=ESRI:54030") : 
>     no system list, errno: 2

I find that changing the `ESRI:54030` to random gibberish gives me the same error message which suggests to me that it can't find the ESRI:54030 information. What do I need to do to get things working?

Note I am running R in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the following link that suggested that `ESRI` is case sensitive in Linux and should be lower-case.

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2011-October/070334.html

changing the code to

```
places_robin_df <- project(cbind(places_df$LONGITUDE, places_df$LATITUDE), proj="+init=esri:54030")
```

fixes things